# Python/OpenCV trackbars, "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rint' "

Tags: python, opencv, object, hough-transform, nonetype

I've recently started learning circle detection with HoughCirlces and wanted to more deeply explore the parameters by turning them into trackbars. Everything runs fine, until a parameter gets too large and I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Benji\Documents\Python Scripts\HoughParameters.py", line 55, in <module>
        Circles()
       File "C:\Users\Benji\Documents\Python Scripts\HoughParameters.py", line 43, in Circles
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2621, in around
        return _wrapit(a, 'round', decimals, out)
       File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 45, in _wrapit
        result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rint'
```

The trackbar limits are set by what should be acceptable for HoughCircles, so I'm guessing it's an issue with how trackbars function that I'm not quite understanding. The code is as follows:

```
    import cv2
    import video
    import sys
    import numpy as np


    def nothing(x):
        pass
    def Circles():
        cv2.namedWindow('Circles')
        cv2.namedWindow('parameters')

        cv2.createTrackbar('dp', 'parameters', 1, 20, nothing)
        cv2.createTrackbar('minDist', 'parameters', 10, 700, nothing)
        cv2.createTrackbar('CannyParam', 'parameters', 1, 300, nothing)
        cv2.createTrackbar('AccumulatorThrs', 'parameters', 1, 100, nothing)
        cv2.createTrackbar('minRadius', 'parameters', 1, 50, nothing)
        cv2.createTrackbar('maxRadius', 'parameters', 51, 700, nothing)


        image = cv2.imread('openCVlogo.png')
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        gray = gray[:,:,2]
        #cv2.imshow('ImageGray', gray)
        while True:
            dp = cv2.getTrackbarPos('dp', 'parameters')
            minDist = cv2.getTrackbarPos('minDist', 'parameters')
            CannyParam = cv2.getTrackbarPos('CannyParam', 'parameters')
            AccumulatorThrs = cv2.getTrackbarPos('AccumulatorThrs', 'parameters')
            minRadius = cv2.getTrackbarPos('minRadius', 'parameters')
            maxRadius = cv2.getTrackbarPos('maxRadius', 'parameters')

            circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,dp,minDist,CannyParam,AccumulatorThrs,minRadius,maxRadius)
            circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

            for i in circles[0,:]:
                cv2.circle(image,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
                cv2.circle(image,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

                cv2.imshow('Circles', image)

             if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    Circles()
```

I'm using the [OpenCV logo](http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/logo_2.png) for a test image. I'd upload a screenshot, but unfortunately this is my first post and I'm not allowed to. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Even just a Google road to jump down.

Comment: Please post the full error traceback!

Comment: Added (I think?) I'm entirely new to code.. This project has been my first attempt after the classic "hello world." Sorry if the indents are a bit off.